# tibco topic subscriptions taking too long

Tags: tibco

I am running into an issue wherein subscriptions to a particular topic on TIBCO is taking too long to get updates. Messages on Other topics published to the same cache are working fine. Any ideas why this would be and what can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you work with TIBCO EMS (there's also another product called TIBCO Rendezvous).

That for a tool called TIBCO Gems is available. It allows you to monitor topics and queues.
That means you should be able to see when your subscriber takes something of the topic (also the acknowledgment action).

Hope that helps

Cheers
      Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

check your topic whether it is synchrous or asynchrous.Synchrous topics will take time. I hope you understand what does synchrous mean else ask me